# WPF TreeView Binding not updating the View

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

INotifyPropertyChanged implemented, DataContext set.

Here is my TreeView:

```
    <TreeView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTreeViewItemExtended}" x:Name="TestCasesTree" MinWidth="220" ItemsSource="{Binding TestCases.Children, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviours:BindableSelectedItemBehavior SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTreeViewItem, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <con:TestAssessmentToImagePathConverter x:Key="TestAssessmentConverter" />
    </TreeView.Resources>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children, Mode=TwoWay}" DataType="{x:Type data:TestCaseNode}">
            <StackPanel Margin="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding TestAssessment, Converter={StaticResource TestAssessmentConverter}}" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                <TextBlock Margin="8 2 0 0" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Binding:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding TestCases.Children, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

BindableBase class:

```
public abstract class BindableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Equals(storage, value))
        {
            return false;
        }

        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected bool CanExecute
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Property:

```
    public TestCaseNode TestCases
    {
        get { return mainWindowModel.TestCases; }
        set
        {
            mainWindowModel.TestCases = value;
            SetProperty(ref _testCases, value);
        }
    }
```

Children:

```
public ObservableCollection<TestCaseNode> Children { get; set; }
```

The place where i edit something:

```
 SelectedTreeViewItem.SetTestAssessmentForCluster(testAssessment);
 OnPropertyChanged("Children");   
 OnPropertyChanged("TestCases");
 OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TestCases));
 OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TestCases.Children));
```

Nothing changes in View (but when i debug it in Visual Studio, i clearly see that the object changes)

This works, but it crashes another things:

```
SelectedTreeViewItem.SetTestAssessmentForCluster(testAssessment);
var tc = TestCases;
TestCases = null;
TestCases = tc;
```

UPD:

TestCaseNode Class:

```
public class TestCaseNode : TestCase, IEquatable<TestCaseNode>, IComparable<TestCaseNode>
{
    public TestCaseNode Parent { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<TestCaseNode> Children { get; set; }

    public void Add(TestCaseNode node) {...}
    public void SetTestAssessmentForCluster(TestAssessment testAssessment, ref TestScores _testScores) {...}
    public bool Equals(TestCaseNode other) {...}
    public override bool Equals(object obj) {...}
    public override int GetHashCode() {...}
    public int CompareTo(TestCaseNode other) {...}
}
```

TestCase Class:

```
public class TestCase
{
    public string Id { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<TestStep> TestSteps { get; set; }
    public TestAssessment TestAssessment { get; set; } = TestAssessment.EMPTY;
}
```

Comment: I think that `OnPropertyChanged("Children");` needs to be invoked from the `TestCaseNode` class - this is where the `ObservableCollection<TestCaseNode> Children` lives - yes?

Comment: So i need to derive the BindableBase class from TestCaseNode? Ok, i'll try it.

Comment: So i derived the BindableBase in TestCaseNode and putted the `OnPropertyChanged("Children")` in the end of the `SetTestAssessmentForCluster` method - it did not work.

Comment: Not derive from BindableBase.  The object that includes the `ObservableCollection<TestCaseNode> Children' must include the `OnPropertyChanged("Children");` call.  That is, the `OnPropertyChanged("Children");` call must be issued by the `TestCases` class.  Please adjust your question to include more of this class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OnPropertyChanged("TestCases");` must be issued by the object that includes the property that changed.  In your case, your class `TestCaseNode` will need to call the `OnPropertyChanged` method in order for the Treeview to recognize the change to the collection because that object holds the collection.  That is, it is not simply some any property named `"TestCases"` that has changed but the property in a specific object.  The reason: you could have more than one properties with this name in different classes.  And, if there are multiple copies of the object, they each have a property with the same name.

What I have done, and this has worked for me, is add a public method within the `TestCaseNode` called `UpdateProperties()` that then calls `OnPropertyChanged("TestCases");`  This ensures that the property update is issued by the correct object.  Then I call this method when I need to have the control updated.

There are several other ways to do the same thing but I find this a simple and direct approach.  You could, for example, include `OnPropertyChanged("TestCases"); in your add method.  I have not done this because 1) the OnPropertyChanged call occurs too often and 2) without the OnPropertyChanged call I can defer the update to the control until after I've made several or all of my Add's.

Comment: So i need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the `TestCaseNode` class? Or i can derive from `BindableBase`,  that already implements that interface and then call `OnPropertyChanged` in `TestCaseNode`?

Comment: Since `TestCaseNode` already derives from `TestCase`, it cannot derive from another class.  You could have `TestCase` derive from `BindableBase` or you could just implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  From what I read, you should just stick with `INotifyPropertyChanged` however, there is no clear evidence either way.

Comment: I derived the `BindableBase` in `TestCaseNode` and putted the `OnPropertyChanged("Children")` in the end of the method that changes the `Children` property. View is still not updating.

Comment: You still need to explicitly call `OnPropertyChanged`  Your changes to the collection do not cause this to occur via the property.

Comment: I understand. I call `OnPropertyChanged` in the method where the property is getting changed.

Comment: Again, no.  You still need to explicitly call `OnPropertyChanged`  _Changes to the collection **do not** cause this to occur via the property._